# What's the difference between friendship and inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

Suppose there are two classes A and B:

```
class A {};
class B {};
```

In what aspects differ the two examples below?

Example 1:

```
class C : public A, public B {};
```

Example 2:

```
class C
{
    //private
    friend class A;
    friend class B;
}
```

Comment: Try calling the methods of A and B on C with the friend version.

Comment: Both concepts are completely different. So the difference is *everything*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Your friends won't be as angry if you don't give them anything in your will.

Comment: what is same in them??

Comment: @JAB: Except in C++ you friends can take everything out of you while you are still alive, while your descendants cannot... C++ is a weird world where friendship grants more than parent-child relationships.

Comment: The difference is what happens if you die intestate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `friend` can touch the `private` parts (pun only slightly intentional! ;) ) of whatever it is friend of, but nothing of `A` and `B` are part of `C` - it just means that "`A` and `B` can touch `C`'s private bits"). Anything "less" than `private` is of course also available to `A` and `B`, so if `C` has `protected` or `public` members, that will also be available.

When you inherit, the `A` and `B` becomes part of `C`. Any `private` sections of `A` and `B` are not available to `C`. In the "is-a" vs. "has-a" nomenclature, `C` now is-a `A` and is-a `B` - in other words, it's inherited from `A`, so it "behaves like `A` from an interface perspective.

Comment: And since the inheritance is public, not only does `C` have an `A` and a `B`, but it *is* both an `A` and a `B`.

Comment: The "private bits" gag always  gets a few laughs, but `friendship` gives access to all the bits, public and non-public (if there were no `protected` it wouldn't be worth making this point).

Comment: @juanchopanza: expanded to cover protected an dpublic.

Answer (score 3):

There are several big differences.  Inheritance and friendship are very different.

With friendship, class C is *NOT* an instance of class A or class B.  Therefore, if you have a function like:

```
void processMyClass(A* a);
```

you cannot pass it an instance of C whereas, if C subclasses A (publicly), it *IS* an instance of A.

With friendship, class A and B can touch all the private member data and functions of C.  With inheritance, class C can touch the public and protected members of A and B.

Friendship is not inherited.  This means, for example:

```
class D : public C
{
private:
   void foo() {
      // A and B cannot call this function
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context you're using, to answer your question to the best of my ability, friends simply allow your classes to share protected/private data, while inheritance will do the same, except there'll be a deeper relationship, where the classes are one in the same (such as with casting).

Comment: I don't think you need the "with casting" qualification.  And friends can also access private data, not just protected data.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers you've gotten are reasonably accurate, I don't think they're really complete. In particular, although they explain *what* the difference between friendship and inheritance is, they don't really explain much about which you should use when, or how the difference affects your code.

The primary use of inheritance (in C++) is to define an interface in a base class, and implement that interface in each of a number of derived classes. The parts of the interface that a derived class *must* implement will normally be signified by pure virtual functions in the base class.

The primary use of `friend`ship in C++ is to define something that forms part of an interface, but for syntactical reasons can't be a member function. One extremely common example is a stream insertion or extraction operator. To implement these as member functions, they'd have to be members of the stream class. Since we don't want to modify the stream class constantly, they're instead free functions that take a reference to a stream as their left parameter, and a reference to a (possibly const) object of the type they insert/extract as their right operand.

These don't *necessarily* have to be `friend`s of the class--they can be written to use only the class' public interface. If you do that, though, it generally means the class is exposing more in its public interface than is otherwise necessary. The interface is no longer minimal, which tends to indicate a problematic design.

One note though: you can define a friend function *inside* a class definition:

```
class Foo { 
// ...
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foo const &f) { 
        // ...
    }
};
```

At first this may seem strange (and syntactically it is, somewhat). Even though it's defined inside the class definition, the `friend` means that this is *not* a member function. At least in my opinion, this reflects its situation fairly accurately: conceptually, it's part of the class. It has access to private members, just like any other member of the class. The fact that it's a free function rather than a member function is purely an implementation artifact that has essentially nothing to do with the code's design.

That also points to another difference between `friend`ship and inheritance: with inheritance, you're normally dealing primarily with member functions. Each member function still receives a `this` pointer, so each member function is directly associated with a specific instance of the class. Yes, you can define it to *also* receive (a pointer or reference to) another instance of the class if desired, but it always receives `this`, regardless. A friend (function or class) doesn't get this--the `friend` declaration just means that the *names* that are private to that other class are visible to the `friend`. To get access to an actual instance of that class, you typically need to pass it as a parameter, or something on that order.

Finally, I'll note that the preceding sort of ignores the possibilities of private or protected inheritance. Private inheritance normally means that the derived class is implemented in terms of the base class. This can be handy if (for example) the derived class is similar to the base class, but isn't related in the design--i.e., you're not asserting that an instance of the derived class can be used anywhere an instance of the base class was needed. Its use of the base class is an implementation detail that the rest of the world doesn't need to know or care about.

Protected inheritance is pretty much a mistake. It's allowed because it's consistent with `public`, `private` and `protected` members (which do make sense) but for inheritance, protected simply doesn't seem to accomplish anything useful.