# When would you use a friend class/function instead of inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

I am not exactly sure what the use of a friend function or class is when you can easily just use inheritance (parent/child classes)? From my understanding, a friend function or class allows a non-member function to access the members of another class that it is declared a friend of. Similarly, a child class can access the members of a parent class. I am wondering, in which situation would you pick one over the other?

Comment: These things (inheritance and `friend`) are not related. You would use whichever solves the problem at hand. They rarely overlap.

Comment: IMHO duplicate link must be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085169/whats-the-difference-between-friendship-and-inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Because you may want to use some private functions/member of a class without being a child of it....

You should read more about inheritance. You can't consider inheritance as a solution to access "members of a class" as you mentioned.